# xidel template extract from button tag

Tags: templates, xidel

```
xidel https://www.url.com/folder -e "<button class="btn" type="BUTTON" onclick="self.location='https://www.url.com/folder/2'">Next &gt;</button>"
```

I am trying to extract what's in between the single quotes with this xidel template and I am getting nowhere fast.

```
<button class="btn" type="BUTTON" onclick="self.location='{.}'">Next &gt;</button>
```

Do I have to escape some characters. The syntax is confusing. I am using this on the commandline on windows, latest version.

Comment: If all you want the output to be is the path of the url, then `-e "$path"` is all you need.

Comment: @Reino How would the syntax look for that?

Comment: Uh, just `xidel https://www.url.com/folder -e "$path"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I tried:

```
xidel -s https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12963528/1/Forced-Return -e "<button>{@onClick}</button>*"
```

but that gave me 5 results of buttons with an onClick attribute, so I needed to be more specific:

```
xidel -s https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12963528/1/Forced-Return -e "<div style='clear:both;text-align:right;'><button>{@onClick}</button></div>"
```

which will output:   self.location='/s/12963528/2/Forced-Return'

So, now we need to get rid of the prefix and single quotes... RegEx is fine for that:

```
xidel -s https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12963528/1/Forced-Return -e "<div style='clear:both;text-align:right;'><button>{extract(@onClick,'=.(.*).',1)}</button></div>"
```

This will output what you wanted:  /s/12963528/2/Forced-Return

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I tried to do the above but it grabs the whole html source code. I just need the url inside the single quotes

Comment: if you can, post the real URL and the text/attribute you need extracted...

Comment: `xidel https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12963528/1/Forced-Return -e "<button class="btn" type="BUTTON" onclick="self.location='/s/12963528/2/Forced-Return'">Next &gt;</button>"` I want this to be the output /s/12963528/2/Forced-Return

Comment: Thanks so much that helped, so xpath and xquery can't deal with single or double quotes escaped properly without regular expressions help. Good to know.

Comment: in xquery/xpath quotes can be substituded by &quot;(double) or &apos; (single), BUT I've already used both single and double quotes in the xidel line, AND xidel parsing seems to substitute them back to ' or " for example in substring-before() and substring-after(), so RegEx was the easy way to go for me...  users BeniBela or Reino (Xidel experts) might know how to escape or circumvent these quotations in different ways.

Comment: I actually tried using &quot; or &apos; on the command line in xidel and they don't work. I'll try to get in contact with the author of xidel and see what he says. I couldn't find anything in the readme or manual on how to deal with properly escaping quotes.

Comment: `extract(@onClick,'&apos;(.+)&apos;',1)` on Windows and `extract(@onClick,"&apos;(.+)&apos;",1)` on Linux work for me. Without xquery `extract(@onClick,'''(.+)''',1)` on Windows and `extract(@onClick,"'\''(.+)'\''",1)` work for me.

Comment: As expected... Reino knows other ways... two of them actually. Thx man!